# Change the components only after data received from 3rd party in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

How does Youtube, Instagram, Github change the content only after they receive data?

```
<Switch>
    ...Other Route
    <Route path = "/" exact component={HomeComp} />
    <Route path = "/articles" component={ArticleComp} />
</Switch>
```

In my knowledge when I click a `Nav Link` to replace url from `/` to `/articles` the component replace from `HomeComp` to `ArticleComp` as well. But what I saw from other SPA application(those I mention above) even though the url is replace but the components aren't replace instead there is an progress bar, components are replace only until receiving response from fetch request. If you can't understand my word I try to include a picture for better understanding

1. If I want to do something like that where should I perform fetch request? From the doc It say it should perform in `componentsDidMount()`. But it seem not right since the component wasn't initial until the data is loaded.
2. Very simple question how can achieve the goal? Replace components only after receiving fetch response rather than  `replace url > replace components > start fetch request`. The solution I seek for is like how github,youtube do(photo below).
3. Can I still stick with react-router if I want to achieve this?

[image]

Sorry for keep repeating the same question, I was worry what I ask is not clear. English is not my primary language so it is really hard for me research, I don't know include what keyword to find the correct solution. If this question is asked before kindly include the link for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So, the assumption here is that you want certain parts of your UI common across different pages. i.e... `HomeComp` and `ArticleComp`.

Imagine that you have a Layout component (container):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Header from './Header';
import Footer from './Footer';

class Layout extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        children: PropTypes.node,
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={_className}>
               <Header />
               <div className={_rhsContentClassName}>
                 { this.props.children }
               </div>
               <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Layout;
```

Now, in your routes file, you describe the routes as,

```
<Switch>
    ...Other Route
    <Route path = "/" exact component={HomeComp} />
    <Route path = "/articles" component={ArticleComp} />
</Switch>
```

and for each of the Route Component, `HomeComp` or `ArticleComp`, your react component should look something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Layout from './Layout';
import Preloader from './Preloader';

class ArticleComp extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };

    componentWillMount() {
         this.setState({ isLoading: true };
         actions
            .fetchData()
            .then(() => {
               // do something
               // store data for the content
               this.setState({ isLoading: false };
            });
    }

    render() {
        if (isLoading) 
          return <Preloader />;

        return (
            <Layout>
               <div> {/* content based on the fetch request */}</div>
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}
export default ArticleComp;
```

This way, you get to segregate your Header, Footer or other static ( or even dynamic concerns ) with the real request-based content.